# CPBarPlot Width/Spacing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am modifying the width of bars in a graph by using `(CPBarPlot *)barPlot.barWidth`, but the spacing between bars does not change and they now overlap each other. `barPlot.barOffset` works great for the initial offset, but I haven't been able to figure out how to change the spacing between subsequent bars. It seems like I have to change something with the spacing of intervals on the axis, but I don't see anything related to interval spacing in `CPBarPlot`. Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a post that might help out with this issue: http://mela.ertale.com/blog/?p=193

Good luck!

Comment: I came across that, but I didn't see anything pertaining to the spacing. I'll have to look through it again.

Comment: It had some good information on setting the width of the entire axis, which I figured might help in modifying space between the bars.

Comment: I figured it out. Rather than explicitly stating the spacing, it figures that out based on the axis ranges. In my case, I had `plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(100.f)];` when I only had two values. Changing the range from 0-2 fixed the problem.